# getting started with SBT for lift

Tags: build, lift, sbt, package-managers

I am a complete newbie to SBT and scala world. I wanna create a lift application and while exploring on how to do it i stumbled everywhere that i must use SBT. So i went to the github wiki page and followed the instructions for windows. I downloaded the jar given there and created sbt.bat and put both the files in c:\sbt and added it to my path. Then i went c:\liftprojects and typed sbt.

It did something but as given everywhere i expected a wizard of some sort which will ask me what kind of project i wanna build and stuff and generate the directory structure just like mvn:archetype:generate but it didnt do anything. It just ran some downloads and created two dirs

```
project
  boot
    blah
  target
    blah
target
  scala 2.8.1
    blah
```

in github wiki it says sbt follows maven bir structure but i cannot see it here.

Am i doin something the wrong way. Im stuck on this. All i need is to know how to create a lift app or a scala project.

Answer (score 4):

To get started with Lift 2.4 my recommendation is to clone the examples repository

`git clone https://github.com/lift/lift_24_sbt`

Then you can use one of the project templates in that repo, with both 2.8 and 2.9 Scala versions. For example, a good way to start with Lift is using the basic project (with Scala 2.8.1 in this example)

`cd lift_24_sbt/scala_28/lift_basic/`

Start `sbt` by typing

`./sbt`

On Windows use `sbt.bat`. Inside the sbt console, type

`update`

`jetty-run`

Open a web browser and point it to http://localhost:8080 to open the Lift application. To stop the application server, simply type `jetty-stop`.
You can use this template project, or the other templates in that repo, as a starting point for your applications.

Lift wiki contains a lot of useful information. Specifically, you can follow the instructions getting started section [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Getting_Started).

Comment: This is exactly how im doing it now, but i wanna understand how sbt works hence the question

Comment: For sbt 0.7.x, you should check project definition in project/build/Project.scala. In order for sbt to know that the project is a Lift one, the class there usually extends DefaultWebProject. May be it is better to post these questions in the Lift mail list [here](groups.google.com/group/liftweb).